# Heroku app fails silently on launch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy an app on Heroku, and I haven't gotten it running yet.  I see the Rails 500 page ("We're sorry, but something went wrong"), but when I `heroku logs` I see nothing interesting:

```
==> exceptional.log <==
# Logfile created on Tue Nov 02 11:27:18 -0700 2010 by logger.rb
[INFO] (init.rb:21) Tue Nov 02 18:27:18 UTC 2010 - Loading Exceptional 2.0.26 for 2.3.5

==> dyno-2858334.log <==
>> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:15336, CTRL+C to stop

==> production.log <==
# Logfile created on Tue Nov 02 11:27:17 -0700 2010
```

As you can see, I've installed the Exceptional addon, and Exceptional hasn't reported any exceptions.

What might fail silently during app launch on Heroku?

Comment: Have you tried committing something trivial to your git repo and repushing to heroku?  Do you have the output of your last `git push heroku` ?

Comment: Were you able to do 'heroku rake db:migrate'? How about opening 'heroku console' and accessing your app through that?

Comment: Yes, both of those worked without any problems.

Comment: @monocle, that helped me. my application was failing silently because my db schema was not migrated properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer: our app was using Sass, which attempts to write its compiled CSS to the `public/` directory.  On Heroku, that's on the read-only filesystem.  Instead, I installed [Hassle](https://github.com/pedro/hassle), which puts compiled Sass CSS under `tmp/`, which is read-write.

Heroku support discovered the problem by setting the environment to `development`, which allowed the error to be logged:

```
heroku config:add RACK_ENV=development
```

The Hassle site recommends adding Hassle as a plugin, but I prefer not to use plugins when I can just use gems.  I got it to work by adding it to the Gemfile, and adding this to `environment.rb`:

```
# existing requires
# ...

require 'hassle'

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  # ...
  # existing config
  # ...

  config.middleware.use Hassle
end
```

Now it just works.

Comment: Just a note... if you're using Rails 3, use this fork of hassle: https://github.com/Papipo/hassle

Answer (score 3):

Try doing (from the root of your app):

```
heroku rake db:migrate
heroku db:push
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you see *Rails's 500 page* means the app is working okay (e.g. it's able to start and produce a 500 error).

One issue might be that your database is not migrated. Try migrating it or upload your development database.